# How to distinguish properties from constants if they both use PascalCasing for naming?

Tags: c#, .net, naming-conventions

As stated in the framework design guidelines and the WWW in general, the current guideline is to name your constants like this

`LastTemplateIndex`
as opposed to
`LAST_TEMPLATE_INDEX`

With the PascalCasing approach, how do you differentiate between a Property and a Constant.
`ErrorCodes.ServerDown` is fine. But what about private constants within your class ? I use quite a lot of them for naming magic numbers.. or for expected values in my unit tests and so on.

The ALL_CAPS style helps me know that it is a constant .

`_testApp.SelectTemplate(LAST_TEMPLATE_INDEX);`

*Disclosure: I have been using the SCREAMING_CAPS style for a while for constants + I find it more readable than squishedTogetherPascalCasedName. It actually STANDS_OUT in a block of text*

Comment: +1 for admitting your problem with SCREAMING_CAPS

Comment: When is it important to know whether a value is a property or constant? (Not sassing you, just curious - I haven't found the distinction to be important, but of course that doesn't mean it isn't.)

Comment: @Jeff - Not sure If I am cooking up examples: When I am hunting for a constant e.g. a DELAY or TIMEOUT in the code... so that I can press F12 and go change it. I guess I've trained my eyes to jump from one screaming constant to another. Hmm.. but then again if I reorganize my internal constants at the top + keep my public constants in a XConstants class, I guess I can live with it.

Comment: @Jeff - OK. Here's another one... Intellisense. I scan for ALL CAPS members to know of defined constants in another type

Comment: @Gishu, what I mean is why do you even care whether a value from another type is a constant, as opposed to a property? When is that significant? Maybe I should ask a SO question myself. ;)

Comment: In VS 2010, the constants have a different icon in Intellisense.

Answer (score 2):

We create a seperate static class to put our constants in and label it Constants.

That way when we access a constant it's always `Constant.YourConstantHere`

so

```
  class NewClass
    {

        static class Constants
        {
            public const int T = -1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've done this too for 'global'/'shared' constants - `TestConstants.SampleProjectPath`. However having one of these constant-containers per class that has internal constants seems like a workaround to me.

Comment: @Gishu I suppose it is a little bit, but it allows us to quickly determine what is a constant and what isn't.  Since most people don't like the ALL_CAPS implementation, this an easy way of differentiating between properties and constants for us.